# Andengine Live wallpaper slow reload

Tags: android, andengine

After making many live wallpapers in andengine , this is the only problem i still face with andengine. 
When i used original extension, When rotating device and returning to home screen from apps there was a blink of screen(unscaled background) and 0,5 sec lag (resources reloading). But i had seen many live wallpapers with out any issue. 
And i had seen this problem mainly in some devices, my tab Iberry give this issue where as Samsung tab don't produce this issue, and as this issue don't give out any error, i cant find it as a report for my App.

**Problem thread**

I had seen this problem being faced by many http://www.andengine.org/forums/live-wallpaper-extension/slow-reload-after-onresume-t4183-70.html

**temporary Solution**

I had Tried out a solution too https://github.com/gigiigig/AndengineLiveWallpaperExtensionImproved
But it has many other problems, So i hope someone can help to find a solution to the slow reload problem that makes the andengine Live wallpaper extension a Question.